# Angular 5 download docx file from c# web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular5, docx

### c# Model:

```
    public class docxModel
    {
        public byte[] testDocx { get; set; }
    }
```

### c# web api file return method code:

```
    byte[] tDocx = File.Exists(wordFilePath) ? File.ReadAllBytes(wordFilePath):null;
    docxModel.testDocx = tDocx;
    return docxModel;
```

### Angular model:

```
    export interface ITestDocxModel {
    testDocx: Blob;
    }
```

### Angular service has a method called CreateWordDoc which will call web api and maps above mentioned c# model to angular model.

### Angular component:

```
    async printToWord() {
        await this.testService.CreateWordDoc()
        .then((res: ITestDocxModel) => {
            this.testModel = res;
            this.testDocx = this.testModel.testDocx;
            var testBlob = new Blob([this.testDocx], { type: 'text/docx' });
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(testBlob);
            window.open(url);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.handleError(err);
        });
    }
```

---

When I call print to word method from button click then it opens up a new window and shows binary data.

I would like it to open word document with save as option.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing the Blob type from `text/docx` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`